# Concrete example of POST request python

Tags: python, post, get

Almost all examples on line for POST and GET request in python are using the same URL (https://api.github.com/events or similar). I'd like to have a real concrete example to understand how it works.

My aim is to download stockexchange data from this website 
https://www.abcbourse.com/download/historiques.aspx

By looking at the HTML code I found the "download button" :
type="submit" name="ctl00$BodyABC$Button1" value="Télécharger" id="ctl00_BodyABC_Button1

and one of the checkbox: #id="ctl00_BodyABC_xcac40p" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$BodyABC$xcac40p" />

I have no idea now how to use to make a script saying 'check the box ***, press the download button'

Any help would be appreciate,

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to learn how to use Python's requests module? Do you want to learn how to scrape webpages for data? Do you want to scrape webpages with requests? Do you want a comparative solution between using requests or another module for data mining?

Comment: I know how to scrape webpages for data with BeautifulSoup. 
I think I want to know how to scrape with requests... however I am not sure what you exactly mean by that.  The last question seems too advance for my knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

it's not so simple here to explain in detail what I would do ... But I can show you a way forward ..., Python's Selenium library makes it possible to generate bots on webpages to perform actions you want. You can through a findElement, localize the check button and press it. I did a recent job using this library and I know that it is perfect for solving your problem.

Comment: I know it's not simple to tell people they need to learn more about what they want before they ask other people how to get it, but please try before suggesting a solution.

Comment: My suggestion was very valid dear! But I can not suggest anything concrete for his problem ... He was superficial in describing the problem ... I can not come up with a ready solution ... I suggested a very efficient Python module for web automation, and with some research it goes solve the problem